# Different jquery effects on specific elements from one div

Tags: jquery, html, css, delay

I have .menu div and inside him .menu-content div with links.
I want to slideDown .menu and after this animation is finished  i want to slideUp .menu-content div. Is this possible? Or can i somehow use wow.js animation that will trigger after sliding down is finished.

This is what i have so far and this just slide down whole div

```
$('.nav-button').click(function() {
    $('.menu').slideToggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.slideToggle()` can take two parameters: The first one is the animation duration, the second one a callback function that is called when the animation is complete. Just use it:

```
$('.nav-button').click(function() {
    $('.menu').slideToggle(
        400,
        function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle(400);
        }
    );
    return false;
});
```

See the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) for more details.